# Lazy Loaded Ember Application

Tags: ember.js, brunch

I am typically searching for answers here but I finlly gotten to the point where I can't find a good answer.

I am looking to build an ember app which only initially loads in the things that it needs just to start and open the main route. All other controllers, views, templates, etc. Would be loaded lazily when a specific route gets triggered.

I have found a good example of how to accomplIsh this here: 
http://madhatted.com/2013/6/29/lazy-loading-with-ember

My main question is to determine what build tools out there support this theory of lazy loading application code? So far, I've seen that Brunch, Yeoman, and Ember App Kit seemed to minify and concatenate all the scripts and templates. I am very happy with minification but need those files separate. I have thought about just putting this code into the app/assets location so that it gets copied over without concat but it does not get minified.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with brunch by adding the following to your brunch config

```
files: {
    javascripts: {
        joinTo: {
            'javascripts/app.js': /^app(\/|\\)(?!admin)/, // concat everything in app, except /app/admin
            'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/,
            'javascripts/admin.js': /^app(\/|\\)admin/ // concat only /app/admin
        }
    }
}
```

Grunt (used in yeoman and ember app kit) is ridiculously flexible, so I'm sure you can set up the same thing there by diving into Gruntfile.js

Comment: "I'm sure you can set up the same thing there by diving into Gruntfile.js": of course — but with MUCH more configuration. Instead of these six lines usual gruntfiles have about 300 lines of code. While they are indeed more flexible, same flexibility can be achieved with more simple tools.

Comment: @rallrall I will try your solution and will mark the answer correct if it indeed will work like that. I suppose my config file could get very verbose if I choose to compile each of my controllers and views like this

Comment: While this solution is not ideal, it would work. In order to accomplish what I was looking to do, I would need to list out each file in my controllers, views, and templates. Also, with brunch, there is a lot of added script to each file created. In practice, this is a huge addition of code of an application tens of thousands of lines. I'll see if anyone else suggests a solution that may work better before accepting this one.

Comment: After looking further, brunch appears to only accept one file in each javascripts and templates to joinTo the same file. In this case, I can't group my controller and view to the same file as the template for that corresponding route. I can only append one or the other.

I have looked into Yeoman with Grunt for the "usemin" feature to group scripts that would be built together. At this point, it appears to be a slightly better way to handle this.

I do realize that I can still use brunch in such a way to generate each file individually as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. This setup will concat -every- file under app (except admin) to app.js, including templates. In the config file, you can also define what templates to compile and add to what js file. E.g. compile all hbs files under /app to app.js, except the ones under /app/admin, which will be added to admin.js

Comment: Just as a side note, I have been using grunt for a year or so, and the simplicity of brunch is a huge relief. Grunt can be a real pain in the ass. So if you get what you want working with brunch, i would highly recommend it :>

Comment: rallrall, my purpose was to load in each file separately except for basic startup scripts (like app.js, initialize.js, routes/, etc.). With brunch, I cannot append controllers/about.js and views/about.js to the same file listed individually. My intent is to lazy load controllers, views, and templates. I was able to configure brunch to do this but I have to list each and every file in my app to do it the way I want it. I believe you thought I was just trying to not concatenate one section of my app. My intent was to not load any scripts that aren't necessary until such time that they are.

Comment: I've finally deemed that this is the simplest solution even though it requires the inclusion of 75% of the application files individually. Other than the sourceMappingURL being off, everything is output as expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The question was: "I am looking to build an ember app which only initially loads in the things that it needs just to start and open the main route. All other controllers, views, templates, etc. Would be loaded lazily when a specific route gets triggered.".

Ember expects to have anything it needs right there when the page gets loaded. I wouldn't be wrong, but lazy loading of routes doesn't seem to be a feature of Ember. Ember CLI is the same. It uses bundling and minification to reduce the overload. But everything should be there to make it work.

Instead, people like me would like to load things only when they are required.

When you try to implement lazy loading in Ember, everything should be represented by a module (file.js): a route, a module; a controller, a module; and so on.
You should follow a schema (like POD), to which apply a mechanism to find things where they are supposed to be.
Every module should know its dependencies. But some of them are very frequent (route, controller, template).
You should use a module loader for the browser. It can be requirejs or whatever you like. But ES6 is at the door. Let's think about that.

Many people use `beforeModel` hook to achieve a result. I did it, and it works, if you don't use `link-to` component. Otherwise everything crashes. Why? Because of `href` computed property. When a `link-to` has been inserted, an `href` is calculated for it. Because of that, Ember looks for the route where the link points to. If the route doesn't exist, one is created from `route:basic`.

A solution could be the preloading of all the routes represented by all link-tos inserted in the page. Too much expensive!

An integration to this answer can be found at [Lazy loading route definitions in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586894/lazy-loading-route-definitions-in-ember-js/34370161#34370161)

For an initial solution to lazy loading of routes organized in POD, have a look at https://github.com/ricottatosta/ember-wiz. It is an ES6 based approach, which relay on SystemJS as module loader.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.